# Can't figure out the logic to solve this challenge

Tags: c#, logic

I am trying to complete a few coding challenges. I am having trouble figuring out the logic to solve this challenge. I am using C#.

The challenge is:

We are given a string called `para = "((()())";` and inside are a bunch of Parentheses. We are also given an `index = 1` where the index is always a value in the string that starts with `(`. So if we converted our `para.ToCharArray`, our `index 1 would = '('`.

With the, code, I have gotten very close to solving it but I can't wrap my head around it.

Below is my code, copy and pasting it should work fine.

```
   string para = "((())())";

    char[] charPara = para.ToCharArray();
    int charParaCount = charPara.Length;

    int index = 1;

    for (int i = index; i < charParaCount; i++)
    {
        if(charPara[index] == '(' && charPara[i] == ')' && charPara[i-1] != '(')
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("index is: " + index + " and i is: " + i);
        }
    }
```

Now, the desired result should be one `WriteLine` with the correct correlating parentheses index. In our case above with an `index = 1`, we do find it and it's `4` but we are also getting the last parentheses index which is `7`.

I am stuck on how to logically solve this problem, any suggestions would be appreciated.

EXAMPLE OF INPUT OUTPUT:

Our input string is `string para = "((())())";` and our input int is `int index = 1;`. The expected output for this would be position `4` because in the char array the `4` would be the closing parentheses for index 1.

Comment: I don't follow the question. Can you give sample input and output?

Comment: I've added an example. Hopefully that clears things up but do let me know @canton7.

Comment: So you're trying to find the index of the matching right paren?

Comment: Yes @Duston ! I added an example of input output in the description (at the bottom) to clarify. My bad if it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a simpler version called parenthesis matching problem, yours need a little bit of more work to find corresponding indexes.
first, you are going to need a stack to push open parenthesis index, if you find any close one, pop one of the members of stack, like this:

```
  string para = "((())())";
    char[] charPara = para.ToCharArray();
    int charParaCount = charPara.Length;
    Stack<int> myStack = new Stack<int>();      
    int index = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < charParaCount; i++)
    {
        if(charPara[i]=='(')
            myStack.Push(i);
        else if(charPara[i]==')'){
            if(myStack.Pop()==index)//if poped index is what we looking for "==index", currently proccesing index "i" will be corresponding parenthesis to it
                return i;
        }
     }
```

remember to use `using System.Collections.Generic;` too

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm going through it now.. I'll let you know how I'm getting on.

Comment: Hey @phalax, I've been going over the solution and it does work but I am struggling to understand the logic. It's quite tricky. Is there a good link to understanding this?

Comment: @OverFlowMars which part exactly is confusing? tell me so i can clear it up or add some more information for you.

Comment: It would be the `if(myStack.Pop() == index)` statement. I can't tell how this is working in the for loop.

Comment: @OverFlowMars this will pop the top element of the stack, which is the last item that got into the stack. just pop it out, you can use another variable to check it like `var temp = myStack.Pop()`. it takes the element out ready to use and delete it from the stack so you can pop other items inside it. you can check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-pop-method-in-c-sharp/ and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-stack-class/

Comment: Hmm I think understand abit more, the statement`if(myStack.Pop == index)` is always popping even when the if statement isn't true right? up until we have out index match.

Comment: It returns the i

Comment: @OverFlowMars yes, that is right. it will pop, then check. one item comes out of the stack no matter what because we reached a closed parenthesis so we need to pop its match

Comment: Yeah I see, that method call in the if statement threw me off. Thanks for the help, it's much appreciated.